# rsyslog7 filter to hostname if no match to regex

Tags: linux, rhel, rsyslog, filter

So I'm extremely new to rsyslog (recently switch from syslog-ng) and I really like that I can have dynamic filenames... My work has recently started using docker and they're sending a lot of fields in the syslogtag to a remote host. So instead of setting up filters for every instance, I'm trying to write a dynamic filter to parse out the relevant details and put it to it's own log/directory such as /var/log/docker/app name/syslog.log

I have the 'app name' working when they're providing the proper delimiters between the fields but when they're not using the proper one, the regex is returning **NO MATCH** and is putting everything to a '/var/log/docker/**NO MATCH**/syslog.log'. Using the **NO MATCH** directory is not an issue but grouping every remote host together in one file is. Is there a way to test if the regex returned no match and then have it change the filename from 'syslog.log' to '%hostname%.log' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not an expert, but you can start with this: you will need to repeat your regexp (I don't know how you can evaluate a template to get the `**NO MATCH**` string).  For example, say your "appname" part is matched by the regexp `[a-z]+:`, then you can write

```
$template nomatch,"/var/log/docker/nomatch/%hostname%.log"
if (not re_match($msg, "[a-z]+:")) then {
   action(type="omfile" dynaFile="nomatch")
   stop
}
```

The `$template` describes your wanted filename, the `if` tries to find the match, and then does the `action` of writing to the file, with no further handling of this message.
The `action()` parameters are described [here](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/master/configuration/modules/omfile.html) in RainerScript.